# nmap scan (part of UDP but full range TCP)

Tags: tcp, udp, nmap

i have a question about nmap scan exactly about part of udp ports but full range tcp ports together...is it possible? I mean that i would like to scan just a few udp ports (most common) but the whole 65535 tcp in one command.

i try this full range but this is very slow

nmap -v -n -sT -sU -p- -sV -sC --open --reason (ip)

i also try

nmap -v -n -sT -sU -p U:53,111,137 T:(here need tips for full range tcp) -sV -sC --open --reason (ip)

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you need to use is: `-p U:53,111,137,T:-`

The `-` part means "all ports" and is equivalent to `1-65535`. Because it comes after the `T:`, it applies only to TCP ports.

You probably also want to use `-sS` instead of `-sT`. Both scan for open TCP ports, but `-sS` lets Nmap have more fine-grained control over scan probes and a better understanding of responses, which leads to faster overall scan times. `-sT` uses generic socket `connect()` calls, which can be less efficient.